# Programming strategy: how to use pointers or reference to increase speed or decrease memory use?

Tags: c++

Suppose I have a function

```
double tauscale(NumericVector x){
  int n = x.size();
  const double k = 2;
  double sc = 1.48*sqrt(median(x*x));
  double tauscale = 0.0;
  for(int i = 0 ; i < n ; ++i){
    tauscale = tauscale + rhobiweight(x(i)/sc,k);
  }
  return (1.0/n)*pow(sc,2)*tauscale;
}
```

Now we see here the function `rhobiweight` that accepts two doubles, currently written as:

```
double rhobiweight(double x,double k = 2.0){
  double rho = 1.0;
  if(std::abs(x)<k){
    rho = 1.0-pow((1.0-pow(x/k,2)),3);
  }
  return rho/Erho(k) ;
}
```

The question is: how can I make use of pointers or references such that the x-value doesn't get copied? Ideally the computation time and memory use should be the same as if I had never written rhobiweight, but implemented this function directly in `tauscale`.

Comment: Make the `rhobiweight` function inline?

Comment: You could keep the same code and ask the compiler to inline the function (it may refuse to do so, though).

Comment: `double tauscale(NumericVector &x)`

Comment: Wrong question: if you need better performance then you should look at optimising the code in `rhobiweight` itself, since it has some obvious low-hanging fruit.

Comment: Ok, so I should declare `double x` and `double k` to be `const` as  Kai Iskratsch suggested, because these variables are parameters that are not be changed. Should the output also be a const ?

Comment: @Ruben declaring by-value parameters `const` is redundant, there is no need or advantage to do that. Changing the by-value return type `const` is not only redundant, but sometimes harmful. It's harmful when the returned type is movable and fast to shallow-copy, but expensive to deep-copy, which does not apply to `double` for which deep and shallow copies are the same, so  returning `const double` is just redundant.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> how can I make use of pointers or references such that the x-value doesn't get copied?

By declaring the arguments as either pointers or references. But don't do that. Then you need to copy the address of the variable, which is just as slow, because the size of a double is same (or nearly same) as the size of a memory address. Not only that, but you need to dereference the pointer whenever you use it in the function. Or dereference it once and copy the value anyway.

> Ideally the computation time and memory use should be the same as if I had never written rhobiweight, but implemented this function directly in tauscale.

That would happen if the function is expanded inline by the optimizer. There is no standard way to force the compiler expand a function inline, but if the optimizer thinks it's advantageous, and you've enabled optimization, it will do that as long as the function is inlinable. To make the function inlinable, make sure that the definition is visible at the call site. A trivial way to do that is to declare the function `inline`.

Note that the peak memory use may actually be higher if many function calls are inlined.

Answer (score 6):

**TL;DR:** Don't try to do this.

**Full story:**

You ask:
"how can I make use of pointers or references such that the x-value doesn't get copied?"

If you are compiling your program with optimization turned on, the variables probably do not get copied anyway. Using pointers and/or references might just make things slower.

This leads me to a more important point: How do you even know that copying the values is taking a long time? Why would you expect that using pointers would take less time?

The way to optimize your code is to *measure* where the time is spent, then try to optimize that.

Comment: _This leads me to a more important point: How do you even know that copying the values is taking a long time? Why would you expect that using pointers would take less time?_  I assumed that would be why you want to use pointers or references.

Comment: the only thing i would do is to declare the input arguments on rhobiweight as const, this often helps optimizers since they know they don't have to copy the variables cause the function does not change them.

Comment: If x(i) would not be a double but a large object for example, would we then have to use pointers or references?

Comment: for large objects it makes sense to pass per reference, preferably per const reference if its not modified

Comment: In most cases, it doesn't matter at all. There are, however, other (and better) reasons to use const references when passing objects as parameters.